# Bean Validation + Resource Bundle ideas?

Tags: java, jpa, validation, bean-validation, resourcebundle

Here is what i want to be able to do with bean validation in my JPA entities :

1. Instead of `@NotNull`, i would like to do `@NotNull(message="keyInMyResourceBundleFile")`
2. I would like also to parameterize the resourceBundle, and i dont know the syntax for it, because it seems to me the message attribute contains only a string.
3. The parameter itself could be i18n-ed. For example, assuming there's a param attribute for the resourcebundle parameters, in English, `@NotNull(message="missing.value", params={"credit card"}) String creditCard;` It will be displayed something like this : "Missing required value for field **credit card**. In Indonesia, it'll be something like "Nilai harus di isi untuk **Kartu Kredit**. In this example, i cant hardcode the "credit card" because in Indonesia, it's "Kartu Kredit"
4. Displays the error message defined in the resource bundle on the log file or UI. Im not sure the way on how to do it, should i catch the `ConstraintViolationException`, get the message, and process the resource bundle by my own code ?

Please share your thoughts on this ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Regarding 1 + 2**

```
@NotNull(message="{keyInMyResourceBundleFile}")
```

Curly brackets are the indicator of a parameter substitution

**Regarding 3**

No idea what you are after. There is no *params* attribute for @NotNull. I guess you would do

`@NotNull(message="{missing.credit.card}")`

And of if you place it on another property you would call the key *{missing.name}*

**Regarding 4**

The *ConstraintViolationException* contains the set of *ConstraintViolation*s. Each *ConstraintViolation* contains the interpolated message as well as the message template. If you want to log it, do it ...

Comment: Could you help clarify what does 'interpolated' mean ? Does it have something to do with the curly braces inside the value of the message attribute ? Regarding no 3 is something like this : In my resourcebundle properties file, i have this simple entry : empty.value=Value for the field {0} is required. And i would like to reuse this "{empty.value}" and pass the parameter that will replace the {0}. For example, "value for field User Id is required", or "value for field Password is required". The intention is to parameterize the value, and pass the value somehow.

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. Interpolated means, that the curly braces {} stand for a key in your message bundle. So in the case of @NotNull(message="{keyInMyResourceBundleFile}") you would need a line 'keyInMyResourceBundleFile=my message' in your properties file. Regarding 3, Bean Validation is unaware of the validated field name. In case you are using JSF you can use {0} which is a special token which will be replaced with the field name. This works, because JSF integrates with Bean Validation with a custom MessageInterpolator.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It's all getting clearer to me. Would like to try out JPA entities with BV + message key, and make use the entity in the JSF Beans to store the state, and reuse the BV. Hopefully this will work fine. Wish me luck !